# React Native TypeScript relative path in WebStorm

Tags: typescript, react-native, import, path, webstorm

Here is my path for variable `color` : `app/theme`

I made package.json in `app/package.json`  with content:

```
{
 "name": "app"
}
```

So I can use in TS files this import:
`import { color } from 'app/theme'` and it works, but WebStorm treat it as a bug:

[image]

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: this is a compiler error - tsc compiler can't find the TypeScript module (.ts file) by specified path. What does your `theme.ts` (or `theme/index.ts` path look like? Is it a module?

Answer (score 0):

Neither WebStorm nor TSC compiler provide support for [this React native hack](https://medium.com/@davidjwoody/how-to-use-absolute-paths-in-react-native-6b06ae3f65d1#.u53b9sdnm) (not officially documented anywhere, as far as I can tell).

You have to configure [path mappings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) in your `tsconfig.json` to get these paths recognized.